# Read data from firebase without any condition on authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android project on firebase, and it requires a user to read data, irrespective of the fact that they are logged in or not. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hit and trial, here is the way that worked out for me

".read": "auth == null || auth !=null",

and click PUBLISH button